# Selenium Test for Check Box

Tags: selenium

I am writing selenium test where admin gives some privileges to user or take away those privileges from user by selecting or deselecting those privileges (these are check-box). There are two groups. To assign a privilege admin selects privileges from left hand side by checking the check-box. Similarly admin takes away privileges by checking the check-box from right hand group. There are also two fields called Add and Remove. Whenever admin gives eg 2 privileges )i.e. checks two check-box, the field Add should be updated to 2Add. Similarly when admin removes privileges eg. checks 3 check-box, field Remove should be updated to 3Remove. These number are superscript. i.e. in 2Add and 3 Remove 2 and 3 are superscript.

I have tried various methods eg. verifyText, verifyTextPresent, but selenium does not identify these fields.

Any help will be appreciated.

Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: Can you post the html and the code you tried along with error you are seeing.

Comment: Bad thing is I am not getting any error message. eg. If I tick 3 check box from left hand side, portal show me 3Add. So when I verify this text with say verifyTextPresent |target: some id | Value = 5Add | selenium should throw error message, but it does not do so. It completely ignores 5Add. HTML tag below as requested: <h4><sup class="counter ng-binding">3</sup>Add</h4>

Answer (score 0):

used verifyText instead of verifyTextPresent in selenium and that did the trick.